# Mysql error when running Hive Query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I see the below error when running hive query. Not able to fix it even after reinstalling hive.Please suggest.

select col1, col2, col3, col4 from y2014_01 order by col4 DESC limit 10;

Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File file:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-1.0.0-bin/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar does not exist)

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: Are you using Mysql as hive metastore?

Comment: Did you put mysql jdbc jar into HIVE_HOME/lib  directory ?

Comment: Yes.. mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jarThe jar is already there. I maintained the following in /etc/environment also. HIVE_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-1.0.0-bin"
HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH="/usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-1.0.0-bin/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar"

Comment: Did you restart the meta store after adding these jars

Comment: i changed the HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH. I removed bin in the mysql connector. It worked.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below points may help you

1. Check whether the jar is present in the correct location or not.
2. Ensure that the jar is not corrupted. Try executing the following command

   jar -tf /usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-1.0.0-bin/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
3. Ensure that this jar is present in the hive metastore host
4. Restart the hivemetastore service after placing this jar.